# Why are Sailor Senshi earthlings?

Tags: sailor-moon

Tuxedo Mask is the protector of Earth, so it makes sense for him to be an earthling.

But what about the Solar System Sailor Senshi? Shouldn't they have been born on their respective planetary bodies, and live there protecting them? Why are they protecting Earth instead?

For example, I would expect Sailor Mars to be a real martian:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer is based on the two* Sailor Moon Crystal *seasons and fan wiki information that I found online. I may edit this in the future, if I ever get to reading the original manga or otherwise come across new information.*

---

The prior incarnations of the Sailor Senshi (i.e. those that came prior to the "present day" of the series) were indeed born on their respective planets. From [the wiki](http://sailormoon.wikia.com/wiki/Sailor_Senshi):

> Act 41 of the manga reveals the Sailor Senshi as princesses of the Solar System. Each one had her own castle, which she can call upon late in the series for power. This act first enables Sailor Moon to transform into Eternal Sailor Moon. The castles are named after moons, except for Mercury's and Venus'. Venus' castle is introduced long before the others', in the Sailor V manga, but she never mentions this to them.

This is supported somewhat by the Mugen arc of *Sailor Moon Crystal*, in which we learn that the Outer Senshi (as their previous incarnations) simply watched over the Solar System from afar, on their own planets.

From this, it is not immediately obvious why the *current* incarnations of the Sailor Senshi show up as human girls on Earth. However, I think that from an in-universe perspective, there are two possible explanations:

1. It is now *the Earth* where the Senshi need to fight the various villians that show up, and that it thus makes sense for the Senshi to be there.
2. The other planets are no longer populated, so it does not make sense for the Sailor Senshi to be reincarnated there.

Comment: But even when each senshi had her own castle, it says "the Sailor Senshi were to support and protect the Moon Princess". Then it makes sense for them to be together, but I don't get why protecting the Moon Princess is more important than their planet.

Comment: @Oriol: when I saw the comments I mention in SMC, I saw them as implying that the Moon was the centre of some sort of extraterrestrial "empire", which might explain it, but I don't know if my reading of _Sailor Moon_ is actually correct. (An additional problem: I wonder how much of the backstory was planned in advance from the get-go, rather than improvised and added later?)